# How can I quickly set up a RESTful site using PHP without a Framework?

Tags: php, rest, redirect

I would like to quickly set up a RESTful site using PHP without learning a PHP Framework. I would like to use a single `.htaccess`-file in Apache or a single rule using Nginx, so I easyli can change web server without changing my code.

So I want to direct all requests to a single PHP-file, and that file takes care of the RESTful-handling and call the right PHP-file.

In example:

1. The user request http://mysite.com/test
2. The server sends all requests to `rest.php`
3. The `rest.php` call `test.php` (maybe with a querystring).

If this can be done, **is there a free PHP-script that works like my `rest.php`?** or **how can I do this PHP-script?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Apache Mod Rewrite:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test$ rest.php [nc]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make a `404 Redirect` to a page called `rest.php`. Use `$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` to examine the url. In `rest.php` you can redirect to wherever you want.

This only requires one rule (`404` in your `.htaccess` file).

You have to be careful and make sure that if the page requested (e.g. mysite.com/test1 doesn't have a test1.php) errors out with a 404 you don't get yourself caught in a loop.

Comment: But I want it for all my pages. So I want that mysite.com/test1 goes to my test1.php-file.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand. If the user requests a file that doesn't exist it will get caught in a redirect loop. That's why you should check to make sure the file exists before redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Modified slightly from the way that [Drupal](http://www.drupal.org) does it.  This redirects everything to rest.php and puts the original requested URL into $_GET['q'] for you do take the appropriate action on.  You can put this in the apache config, or in your .htaccess.  Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rest.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If all you then want to do is include the requested file, you can do something like this

```
<?php
  if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {
    $source = $_GET['q'] . '.php';
    if (is_file($source)) {
      include $source;
    } else {
      echo "Source missing.";
    }
  }
?>
```

You really don't want to do that, however; if someone were to request '/../../../etc/passwd', for example, you might end up serving up something you don't want to.

Something more like this is safer, I suppose.

```
 <?php
  if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {
    $request = $_GET['q'];
    switch ($request) {
      case 'test1':
        include 'test1.php';
        break;
      default:
        echo 'Unrecognised request.';
        break;
    }
  }
  ?>
```